# Why the "cursor.lastrowid" return 3?

Tags: python, mysql-python

Below is my RUN_SQL function:

```
def RUN_SQL_SAFE(sql, input_tuple=(), get_update_id=False, debug = False):
    conn = GET_MYSQL_CONNECTION()
    cursor = conn.cursor(cursorclass=MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
    cursor.execute(sql, input_tuple)
    conn.commit()
    if get_update_id:
        res = cursor.lastrowid
    cursor.close()
    conn.close()
    if get_update_id:
        return res
```

I run my code using "RUN_SQL_SAFE(sql, tuple, True)", here sql is a insert sql and the table is empty but return res with 3. I wonder to know why it doesn't return 1??
Thanks

Comment: There's no need to [shout](http://email.about.com/od/netiquettetips/qt/Writing-In-All-Caps-Is-Like-Shouting.htm) when defining functions. Have a look at [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the table has been in use before an therefore has an `AUTO_INCREMENT` value `> 1`...

BTW: I don't think that this repeated `if get_update_id:` is very elegant. Instead, you could do

```
def run_sql_safe(sql, input_tuple=(), get_update_id=False, debug = False):
    from contextlib import closing
    conn = get_mysql_connection()
    with closing(conn):
        cursor = conn.cursor(cursorclass=MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
        with closing(cursor):
            cursor.execute(sql, input_tuple)
            conn.commit()
            if get_update_id:
                return cursor.lastrowid
```

If you could tell your connection to have `MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor` as its "basic cursor class", you could even do

```
def run_sql_safe(sql, input_tuple=(), get_update_id=False, debug = False):
    from contextlib import closing
    conn = get_mysql_connection(cursorclass=MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
    with closing(conn):
        with conn as cursor:
            cursor.execute(sql, input_tuple)
            if get_update_id:
                return cursor.lastrowid
```

which does this commit automatically.